# Phaser check if sprite is inside another sprite not working?

Tags: javascript, css, html, phaser-framework

I am checking if one sprite is inside another sprite using this JS.

```
    if (ball.x > cup.x &&
        ball.x + ball.width < cup.x + cup.width &&
        ball.y > cup.y &&
        ball.y + ball.height < cup.y + cup.height) {
        game.paused = true;
    }
```

So I am checking if my 'ball' sprite is inside the bounding rectangle of 'cup'.

However, sometimes the game is not being paused, even though visually I can see that 'ball' is inside 'cup'.  My conditional statement is correct, right?  Sometimes it works as intended, sometimes it doesn't, which is extremely frustrating as it generates no tracable error messages...

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
<body>

<script src="js/phaser.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**game.js**

```
window.onload = function() {

    var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

    function preload() {
        game.load.image('table', 'assets/img/table.png');
        game.load.image('cup', 'assets/img/cup.png');
        game.load.image('ball', 'assets/img/ball.png');
    }

    var table;
    var cups;
    var p1cups;
    var p2cups;
    var ball;
    var bounces = 0;
    var ballAscending = true;
    var ballThrown = false;
    var checkCollisions = true;
    var goalScored = false;
    var cupW;
    var cupH;
    var gameOver = false;
    var clickTime;

    function create() {

        game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

        table = game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, 'table');
        table.anchor.setTo(0.5,0.5);

        cupW = game.cache.getImage('cup').width;
        cupH = game.cache.getImage('cup').height;

        p1cups = game.add.group();
        p1cups.create(game.world.centerX, cupH / 2, 'cup');
        p1cups.create(game.world.centerX - cupW, cupH / 2, 'cup');
        p1cups.create(game.world.centerX + cupW, cupH / 2, 'cup');
        p1cups.create(game.world.centerX - cupW / 2, cupH + (cupH / 2), 'cup');
        p1cups.create(game.world.centerX + cupW / 2, cupH + (cupH / 2), 'cup');
        p1cups.create(game.world.centerX, (cupH * 2) + (cupH / 2), 'cup');

        p2cups = game.add.group();
        p2cups.create(game.world.centerX, game.world.height - (cupH / 2), 'cup');
        p2cups.create(game.world.centerX - cupW, game.world.height - (cupH / 2), 'cup');
        p2cups.create(game.world.centerX + cupW, game.world.height - (cupH / 2), 'cup');
        p2cups.create(game.world.centerX - cupW / 2, game.world.height - (cupH / 2) - cupH, 'cup');
        p2cups.create(game.world.centerX + cupW / 2, game.world.height - (cupH / 2) - cupH, 'cup');
        p2cups.create(game.world.centerX, game.world.height - (cupH / 2) - (cupH * 2), 'cup');

        ball = game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY + (cupH*4),'ball');
        ball.anchor.setTo(0.5,0.5);
        ball.z = 0;
        ball.checkWorldBounds = true;
        ball.events.onOutOfBounds.add(restart,this);

        game.physics.enable([ball, p1cups,p2cups],Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

        p1cups.forEach(function(item) {
            item.anchor.setTo(0.5);
            item.body.immovable = true;
        },this);

        p2cups.forEach(function(item) {
            item.anchor.setTo(0.5);
            item.body.immovable = true;
        },this);

        ball.body.bounce.set(0.50);
        ball.body.drag.set(20);
        ball.body.allowRotation = false;

        game.stage.backgroundColor = "#d3d3d3";

        game.input.onDown.add(onDown,this);
        game.input.onUp.add(throwBall,this);

        console.log(ball.scale);
    }

    function onDown() {
        clickTime = game.time.time;
    }

    function throwBall() {
        if (ballThrown == false) {
            var delta = game.time.time - clickTime;
            game.physics.arcade.velocityFromAngle(ball.angle, delta, ball.body.velocity);
            ballThrown = true;  
        }   
    }

    function update() {

        ball.rotation = game.physics.arcade.angleToPointer(ball);

        if (ballThrown) {

            game.physics.arcade.collide(ball,p1cups,collisionHandler,collisionProcess,this);    
            game.physics.arcade.collide(ball,p2cups,collisionHandler,collisionProcess,this);

            if (ballAscending) {
                ball.z = ball.z + 2;
                if (ball.z > 100 - bounces * 20) {
                    ballAscending = false;
                }
            } else {
                ball.z = ball.z - 2;
                if (ball.z < 1) {
                    bounces = bounces + 1;
                    ballAscending = true;
                }
            }

            ball.scale.set((ball.z + 100) / 100);

            if (Math.abs(ball.body.velocity.x) < 1 && Math.abs(ball.body.velocity.y) < 1 && ball.scale.x == 1) {
                restart();
            }

        }

    }

    function restart() {
        ball.body.velocity.set(0);
        ball.inputEnabled = true;
        ball.z = 0;
        bounces = 0;
        ball.position.x = game.world.centerX;
        ball.position.y = game.world.centerY + (cupH*4);
        ball.scale.set(1);
        ballThrown = false;
        checkCollisions = true;
        goalScored = false;
    }

    function collisionHandler(ball,cup) {
        return true;
    }

    function collisionProcess(ball,cup) {

        if (ball.x > cup.x &&
            ball.x + ball.width < cup.x + cup.width &&
            ball.y > cup.y &&
            ball.y + ball.height < cup.y + cup.height) {
            game.paused = true;
        }

        return false;

    }

}
```

Comment: We need to be able to reproduce the behavior described. Can you show us an *minimal* example of this in action?

Comment: Sure, I will make a JSFiddle and just post the exact code I am using, It's about 150 lines.  One second...

Comment: Just updated my question with the exact source of my game, hope that helps...take note that the problem is occurring n my collisionProcess function.  Sometimes my conditional in the function is evaluating to 'true' correctly, sometimes it is not.

Comment: when asking, try to make a short example that clearly illustrates your problem. We are lazy people, and we probably won't read your full question if it is not easy to understand :S

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether or not a phaser rectangle is contained into another rectangle, you can use the `Phaser.Rectangle.containsRect` function.

Since a sprite is a phaser rectangle, you can do this:

```
var a = game.add.sprite(100,100, 'a');
var b = game.add.sprite(120,120, 'b');
game.physics.arcade.enable(a);
game.physics.arcade.enable(b);

// this will print whether or not a is contained inside b
console.log(Phaser.Rectangle.containsRect(a.body, b.body));
```

ohbtw, you are using the arcade physics system... if you are looking for complex geometric maneuvers, you should probably use the P2 system ;)